# postgresql extract substring from some position

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named marc  and column named tag
this column contain a text like this:

```
"|a john dumas .|d 1941|e united states|=^A22306"
```

I want to read this text and extract only a substring which is between `|a` and `|d`.

the text should be this: `john dumas.1941`

I tried without success with:

```
select regexp_replace(tag, '(.*)_[^|][^a][^d]*$', '\1')
from marc where id='10825700016';
```

can someone help me to solve this problem

Comment: This is probably [MARC-21](https://www.loc.gov/marc/bibliographic/). You may be better off extracting it field-by-field before loading it into a table. It's not guaranteed that the `d` item follows the `a` item always.

Comment: how can I divide this string in substring like this 
|a john dumas .  and    |e united states  and  |d 1941 and |=^A22306


and after that choose only |a john dumas .  and |d 1941

and after that replace |a and |d with space

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring()` to extract the part between `|a` and `|e`.

Then use `replace()` to get rid of the `.|d`

```
replace(substring(tag from '\|a(.+)\|e'), '.|d', '')
```

Comment: Well,
I did not see there was an answer.  Was busy writing DBFiddle.
This is also correct answer :) +1

Comment: thank you for your response , the output is correct.
but I have a problem  when the text become like this :'|a john dumas .|e united states |d 1941 |=^A22306'

the output is not correct " john dumas . "

|a is all time in the beginning of text but |d can be in the middle or in the end of text .

Answer (score 0):

> I want to read this text and extract only a substring which is between
> |a and |d.

You can do it using String functions such as `CONCAT` and `substring` like in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/hUH4hRQg)

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        trim(substring(tag, position('|a' in tag) + 2, position('|d' in tag) - position('|a' in tag) - 3)),
        '.',
        trim(substring(tag, position('|d' in tag) + 2, position('|e' in tag) - position('|d' in tag) - 2))
    ) AS extracted_string
FROM marc
WHERE id = '10825700016';
```

The trim function will also remove the leading spaces before `john` and after `dumas`

Output:

```
extracted_string
john dumas.1941
```

Comment: thank you for your response , the output is correct.
but I have a problem  when the text become like this :'|a john dumas .|e united states |d 1941 |=^A22306'  the output is negative substring length not allowed
|a is all time in the beginning of text but |d can be in the middle or in the end of text

Comment: I think that the solution is to divide the text in substring using split_part like this |a john dumas . and |e united states and |d 1941 and |=^A22306 and after that choose only |a john dumas . and |d 1941 and after that replace |a and |d with space
can someone help me to solve this problem